# boost::xtime nsec only gives a 1 second resolution on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost

When I use Boost's boost::xtime_get function to get the current time, the nsec field gives a resolution of only a second.  I'm not expecting nanosecond resolution, but why is it this poor?  All the Googling I've done seems to imply that I should get a few milliseconds resolution on Linux.  I can't seem to find an alternative either - time.h functions are also on a 1s resolution...

Boost version 1.43
Ubuntu 10.04
GCC 4.4.3

If anyone can shed any light I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Why are you using that in the first place? Why not `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()`?

Comment: what do you mean "the nsec field gives a resolution of only a second" ? is nsec always 0 ? if it not, then it's not a resolution of "only a second". the nsec field only contain the number of nanoseconds since the epoch, modulo 1 000 000 000

Comment: Check if `BOOST_HAS_GETTIMEOFDAY` is defined. When not, `xtime_get`  will call `boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time()`, although it would be very strange to not see it defined on a Linux system.

Comment: First, @ildjarn - thanks, wasn't aware of that but it works!  Although it doesn't explain my problem using xtime it is the alternative I was looking for, I would be happy to give the answer to you if you added an answer ;)

Comment: @Cubbi - thanks for the suggestion but it is defined.

Comment: @BatchyX - sorry, I should have been clearer.  It isn't that nsec is always 0, it's that is only updates once every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::xtime_get` hasn't been an officially supported part of Boost.Thread since Boost 1.34.1. Boost.Thread was rewritten from scratch in 1.35, and `xtime_get` only remains for backwards compatibility with pre-1.35 code.

Even in 1.34.1, it was documented as:

> This is a temporary solution that will be replaced by a more robust time library once available in Boost.
>
> The `xtime` type is used to represent a point on some time scale or a duration in time. This type may be proposed for the C standard by Markus Kuhn. Boost.Thread provides only a very minimal implementation of this proposal; it is expected that a full implementation (or some other time library) will be provided in Boost as a separate library, at which time Boost.Thread will deprecate its own implementation.

That "other time library" is of course [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/date_time/doc/index.html) (which incidentally was introduced in Boost 1.32, so it seems the Boost.Thread docs between 1.32 and 1.34.1 weren't updated). It appears to me that the Boost.Date_Time functionality you're looking for is either `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()` or `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()`, which are documented in the [Posix Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) section of the docs.